# Count() with multiple conditions in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to see how many times a player has lost a match at any of his favourite stadiums. I've tried the following, but it is not returning the correct values:

```
select players.name,
count (case when players.team <> matches.winner and favstadiums.stadium = matches.stadium then 1 else null end) as LOSSES
from players
join favstadiums
on favstadiums.player = players.name 
join matches
on favstadiums.stadium = matches.stadium
group by players.name;
```

I've also tried left/right joins, but it makes no difference in the output.

Here is the relational diagram of the database for reference:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You should use a numeric ID for each table (player.id, team.id, etc...)

Comment: @ToddMoses if you do that, at least make them meaningful: player.playerid, team.teamid.  Otherwise your query will be full of a bunch of "id" this and "id" that, and make little sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `join` condition doesn't have the player playing in the stadium.  You need to add the condition that the player's team played in the favorite stadium:

```
select players.name,
       SUM(case when players.team <> matches.winner then 1 else 0 end) as Losses
from players join
     favstadiums
     on favstadiums.player = players.name join
     matches
     on favstadiums.stadium = matches.stadium and
        players.team in (matches.home, matches.away)
group by players.name;
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling this was the reason, but didn't know how to add it. Also do you know how I can get rid of rows with 0 losses. I tried adding `and Losses is not null` before the `group by`, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT  P.name,
        COUNT(DISTINCT M.ID) AS Losses
FROM Player P
INNER JOIN favStadiums FS
    ON P.name = FS.player
INNER JOIN Match M
    ON (P.team = M.home OR P.team = M.away)
WHERE FS.stadium = M.stadium
AND M.winner <> P.team
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, check it out

```
select player.name,
count(match.id) as LOSSES
from player
inner join team
    on player.team = team.name 
left join match
    inner join favStadiums on favstadiums.stadium = matches.stadium and favStadiums.player = player.name
    on (match.home = team.name or match.away = team.name) and match.winner <> team.name     
group by players.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another thrown into the mix...  I indent my joins to show relation of how I get to the details.

```
SELECT
      P.`Name`,
      SUM( case when P.team <> M.winner then 1 else 0 end ) as FavStadiumLosses
   from
      Player P
         Join Match M
            ON P.Team = M.`Home`
            OR P.Team = M.Away
            Join Stadium S
               ON M.Stadium = S.Stadium
               JOIN FavStadiums FS
                  ON P.`Name` = FS.Player
                  AND M.Stadium = FS.Stadium
   group by
      P.`Name`
```